# do I need WAI-ARIA attribute aria-labelledby on nested input element?

Tags: html, wai-aria

Is the attribute `aria-labelledby` needed on an `<input>` element that is nested inside a `<label>` element that serves as a label for `<input>`? Like below:

```
<label>This is an input field:
  <input type="text" />
</label>
```

or do I need something like:

```
<label id="mylabel">This is an input field:
  <input type="text" aria-labelledby="mylabel" />
</label>
```

I know that the `for` attribute is not needed on `<label>` if the target of `for` is nested, does the same principle apply to the ARIA attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `<input>` tag is present inside the `<label>` tag, you don't need to use aria-labelledby attribute.
But, if you are writing like this :

`<div> Enter some text here:
  <input type="text"/> 
</div>`

Then, you need to use aria-labelledby on `<input>` tag like this:

`<div id="txt"> Enter some text here:
  <input type="text" aria-labelledby="txt">
</div>`